# Kestrel server claims to be listen in a port but it does not

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localhost, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel

I have an Asp .net core 3.0 web api,  when I set up any ASPNETCORE_URLS enviarment variable (eg http://0.0.0.0:5100) and run the Kestrel sever, the Kestrel console claims that its listening from that address, but when I put it in the browser nothing happens. Only runs with localhost, even in the Program.cs, the webBuilder.UseUrls() only works with localhost:{port} urls, changing the port number. Am I missing something???

Comment: for env vars you must specify "*" instead of "0.0.0.0" for any IP: `SET ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://*:5100`

Comment: https://*:5100, only works when i put localhost:5100, and i want connect other devices to these api

Comment: have you opened the port in your firewall?

Comment: I forgot, i did an inbound in the firewall and it work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If UFW is enabled you can run this command to enable port `5100`: `sudo ufw allow 5100`. If you want to only accept a specific source IP address, this command can be run: `sudo ufw allow from 192.168.100.50 to any port 5100` Which translates to allow access for device with source IP `192.168.100.50` to port `5100`.